# PHPMyAdmin EDIT and EXECUTE buttons disabled for Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, phpmyadmin, procedure

I created a couple of stored procedures in a remote MySql database (web) a week ago... during the session where I created them I was able to edit them, export them, etc...

Now, a week later, I wanted to edit them, and I find that the Edit and Execute buttons in the Routines tab for those two are disabled...

[image: Routines tab]

My web server is running phpmyadmin 4.0.10.7

I found out that, for some reason, in the ROUTINES table of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA db, those routines (procedures) have a different DEFINER (well, not different, but the db considers them different)

[image: Definers for the procedures]

This is why I can't edit them... So, finally, the scenario is this. I logged in to my CPanel and PHPMyAdmin as usual, created those procedures, and the DEFINER for them is user@icario.servidoraweb.net (my user + the domain is my hosting provider)... Then, when I tried to edit them a week later, I log in, and I find that my user now (running SELECT CURRENT_USER();) is "user@10.0.5.47"...

I open a ticket with my hosting provider to find out why now my login to CPanel contains the IP address instead of the domain name, and they say they have no idea, they didn't change anything.

Now, Yesterday I logged in again, and then I can edit those procedures, I check my user, and it is again "user@icaro..."

Today, when I log in again, I am back in "user@10.0..."

So... I know why I can't edit those procedures... what I don't know is why I sometimes my user has the domain name, and sometimes the IP address..

Any ideas on this?? Thanks

Comment: have you looked  your services enable or not ? at this path :  Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\services

Comment: Facing the same issue here... Have you got any solution?